# Material UI form validation issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im using Material UI to create a new user..the nonprofit is optional. But I'm having an issue with validating the form then breaking out of the validation so I can send the users data to axios POST request. any help would be appreciated.

Im not sure how to refactor this code to allow me to do this. I tried a custom hook and made a new file but I just got all confused.

```html
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& .MuiTextField-root': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 288,
      borderRadius: 8,
    },
  },
  button: {
    width: 288,
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
}));

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
export default function CreateAccountMuiForm() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState('');
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState('');
  // const [nonProfitError, setNonProfitError] = useState('');
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const handleClickShowPassword = () => setShowPassword(!showPassword);
  const handleMouseDownPassword = () => setShowPassword(!showPassword);

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    nonProfit: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // sets intial state to false
    setEmailError(false);
    setPasswordError(false);

    //   // form validation happens here after submited

    //   // this checks to make sure a valid email is input
    if (values.email === '') {
      setEmailError(true);
    } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(values.email)) {
      setEmailError(true);
    }

    // this checks to make sure password is greater than 5
    if (values.password === '') {
      setPasswordError(true);
    } else if (values.password.length < 5) {
      setPasswordError(true);
    }
    // this checks to make sure both validations are true
    if (values.email && values.password) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(values);
    }
    return
  };

  return (
    <FormControl>
      <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <TextField
            name="email"
            id="outlined-password-input"
            placeholder="Email"
            type="email"
            autoComplete="current-email"
            variant="outlined"
            required
            error={emailError}
            value={values.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            // onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
          <TextField
            name="password"
            id="password"
            placeholder="password"
            type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
            autoComplete="current-password"
            variant="outlined"
            required
            error={passwordError}
            value={values.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            // onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            InputProps={{ // <-- This is where the toggle button is added.
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                  <IconButton
                    aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                    onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                    onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                  >
                    {showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                  </IconButton>
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
          />
          <TextField
            name="nonProfit"
            id="nonProfit"
            placeholder="Select you nonprofit (optional)"
            type="text"
            autoComplete="none"
            variant="outlined"
            // onChange={(e) => setNonProfit(e.target.value)}
            value={values.nonProfit}
            onChange={handleChange}
            // error={nonProfitError}
          />
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            type="submit"
            className={classes.button}
          >
            Create an account
          </Button>
          <p className="terms-of-use">
            By creating an account you agree to our
            <Link to="/termsofuse" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: '#909090' }}>
              <strong> Terms of use</strong>
            </Link>
          </p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL; DR:** Follow *low coupling* and *high cohesion* principles: separate the state values and pair them with their error states so you can validate via hooks.

**NL; PR:** Excellent question, this is often overlooked in tutorials. In this [pastebin](https://codesandbox.io/s/answer-to-material-ui-form-validation-issues-9jw0i) you can observe a way to do so. These are the relevant snippets:

### Don't

- High coupling: unnecessary dependency among state values:

```js
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    nonProfit: '',
  });
```

- Low cohesion: error state is derived from another value:

```js
const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState('');
```

### Do

- Low coupling: separate state handling for each value, high cohesion: email value and error are handled in one place (a hook).

```js
const useEmailValidator = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState(false);
  const handleAndValidateEmail = useCallback((value) => {
    setEmailError(!(value && /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(value)));
    setValue(value);
  }, []);

  return [value, handleAndValidateEmail, emailError];
};
```

Try refactoring the other state values and errors using validator hooks.

Finally, if you are feeling adventurous, consider the *DRY* principle and try [form management libraries](https://next.material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#complementary-projects).

Comment: Would you create a separate function for the POST request and then put that in the return? Or break  out of that function then create a whole other function for the submit to send the post request?

Comment: I updated the example =), since the submit requires several state values to be validated (they cannot be decoupled), I modified your handleSubmit function to check for errors before performing an Axios fetch.